# What does summation EVEN and summation ODD exactly mean in truth table of IC 74180 which is used as a parity generator and parity checker?

Tags: electronics, digital-communication

[image: Truth Table of IC 74180 as given on ti.com]

I was trying to implement parity generator for 8 bit message using IC 74180. I understand the purpose of all the pins but don't what do those two output pins namely summation(Even) and summation(odd) mean? I couldn't find any clear explanation anywhere else.

Comment: it is `sum` ... the sum of `1` bits

Comment: don't forget that the IC is a parity bit generator ... so the output is a parity bit for the input bits

Comment: Doesn't the truth table give it to you?

Answer (score 0):

> The word-length capability is easily expanded by cascading.

Even and Odd come from a previous 74180 to allow more than 8 bits of parity.

∑Even will be true if all 8 bits AND Even are an even number.  Even true + 00000000 means ∑Even is true.

Even false + 00000001 means ∑Even is true.  Odd parity from previous sections and odd parity in this section means even parity.